# Ошибка в программе бота в вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
import vk_api
import time
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


 vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token ='я убрал')
 vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, я убрал)


 for event in longpoll.listen():
if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
    if event.object.text.lower() == 'калькулятор':
     vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id, message='Включаю калькулятор', random_id=0)
        vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id, message='Введите первое число', random_id=0)
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                a = event.object.text.lower()
           vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id, message='Введите второе число',random_id=0)
                for event in longpoll.listen():
                    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                        b = event.object.text.lower()
                vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id, message='Что делtv(+,-)',random_id=0)
                        for event in longpoll.listen():
                            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                                wh = event.object.text.lower()
                                if wh == "+":
                                    s = int(a) + int(b)
            vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id, message='Сумма равна ' str(s),random_id=0)
                                elif wh == "-":
                                    s = int(a) - int(b)
     vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id, message='Разность равна ' + str(s), random_id=0)
                                else:
     vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id,message='Выбрананеверная операция!!',random_id=0)
```

Первый раз программа запустилась идеально. Я начал набирать "калькулятор" второй раз, и мне выдало "Выбрана неверная операция!!". Что делать? Как избавится от цикла и чтобы все работало. Заранее спасибо

Comment: У вас очень большие проблемы с отступами в коде, который вы добавили в вопрос. Он вообще не запустится. Вставьте код в вопрос именно в том виде, в котором он у вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя делать такое большое кол-во циклов, тк если один игрок зайдет в один блок, то всех остальных также туда закинет

```
for event longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        text = event.object.text.lower()
        if "реши" in text:
            text = text.split("реши")[-1]
            try:
                answer = eval(text)
                vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id, message=f"Ответ: {answer}",random_id=0)
            except:
                vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id, message="Ошибка",random_id=0)
```

Для того, чтобы калькулятор сработал, игроку нужно будет ввести команду: Реши [пример]
К примеру: Реши 5+5

Comment: А можете объяснитькак это работает. И огромное спасибо

Comment: @Mamora, гугл в помощь ;)

Comment: Хорошо,огромное спасибо. Почти месяц искал на разных форумах